# SUM the result of a group by query

Tags: sql-server

I have a following query running in SQL Server that returns the count and the city:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*), city 
FROM 
    address 
WHERE
    address1 LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
    AND phone1 LIKE '%[0-9]%'
GROUP BY
    city
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 250
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC
```

I get the following result:

```
1232 Atlanta
345 Chicago
```

How can I write a query to get the sum of the result of the counts (1232 + 345 in the above example?)

I have tried subqueries, but seems to cause some errors because of the group.. New to SQL and my apologies for a poor question.

Comment: Do you want to get both the shown result (i.e. the two records) **AND** the total in a single query, or only the total?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way using `SUM Over()` window aggregate function

```
SELECT city,
       Count(*) AS total,
       Sum(Count(*))OVER() grand_total
FROM   address
WHERE  address1 LIKE '%[0-9]%'
       AND phone1 LIKE '%[0-9]%'
GROUP  BY city
HAVING Count(*) > 250
```

Comment: Thanks - OVER() is what I will use.. very compact.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select sum(c)
from (
    select COUNT(*) c
    from address
    where address1 like '%[0-9]%'
        and phone1 like '%[0-9]%'
    group by city
    having count(*) > 250
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define a CTE and then use it:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT city, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM address
    WHERE address1 LIKE '%[0-9]%' AND
          phone1 LIKE '%[0-9]%'
    GROUP BY city
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 250
)

SELECT t.city,
       t.total,
       (SELECT SUM(total) FROM cte) AS grand_total
FROM cte t
ORDER BY t.total DESC
```

If you just want the grand total then use the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(total) AS grand_total
FROM cte
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! Appreciate the answer - I learnt from you that you can use multiple select statements in a query and the WITH command

Comment: Yes, of course! Thanks again.. I wish there were some options to choose multiple answers where I learn from

Answer (score 1):

you can use ROLLUP of GROUP,For example:

```
    ;WITH address(address1,phone1,city) AS
    (
        SELECT '1','2','Atlanta' UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2','2','Atlanta' UNION ALL 
        SELECT '3','2','Atlanta' UNION ALL 
        SELECT '4','2','Atlanta' UNION ALL 
        SELECT '5','2','Chicago' UNION ALL 
        SELECT '6','0','Chicago' UNION ALL 
        SELECT '7','0','Chicago'
    )
    SELECT COUNT(*), ISNULL(city,'Summary') FROM address where
    address1 LIKE '%[0-9]%'
    and phone1 LIKE '%[0-9]%'
    group by city WITH ROLLUP
    HAVING count(*) > 2
    order BY CASE WHEN city IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END , COUNT(*) DESC
```

```
----------- -------
4           Atlanta
3           Chicago
7           Summary
```